# Помогите, пожалуйста, с авторизацией на сайте

Tags: php, sql, база-данных, авторизация, steam-web-api

Помогите, пожалуйста, хочу сделать авторизацию на сайте с помощью Steam api, при которой после авторизации через Steam будут получены id стима и nickname на основе которых в базе данных (mysql) будет создаваться профиль с доп. параметрами, и когда в следующий раз пользователь авторизуется через Steam из базы данных по is стима и никнейму загрузятся остальные данные профиля.У меня получается только получить данные из стима(никнейм и айди), а дальше не понимаю как делать. Вот ссылка на проект авторизации через steam которую использую я https://github.com/SmItH197/SteamAuthentication

```
<?php
ob_start();
session_start();

function logoutbutton() {
echo "<form action='' method='get'><button style='position:absolute; 
right:3%; margin-top:-25px; width:80px; height:30px; border-radius:4px; 
background-color:#ffda00;' name='logout' type='submit'>Выйти</button> 
</form>"; 
 //logout button
 }

 function loginbutton($buttonstyle = "square") {
$button['rectangle'] = "01";
$button['square'] = "02";
$button = '<a href="?login"><div id="blink1" style="position:absolute; 
right:0; top:35px; padding-top:7px;"><img  
src="http://rlgl/opencasepages/steamauth/LOGININTOSTEAM.png" width="240px"> 
</div></a>';

echo $button;
}
if (isset($_GET['login'])){
   require 'openid.php';
  try {
    require 'SteamConfig.php';
    $openid = new LightOpenID($steamauth['domainname']);
    if(!$openid->mode) {
        $openid->identity = 'https://steamcommunity.com/openid';
        header('Location: ' . $openid->authUrl());
    } elseif ($openid->mode == 'cancel') {
        echo 'User has canceled authentication!';
    } else {
        if($openid->validate()) {
            $id = $openid->identity;
            $ptn = "/^https?:\/\/steamcommunity\.com\/openid\/id\/(7[0-9] 
{15,25}+)$/";
            preg_match($ptn, $id, $matches);
            $_SESSION['steamid'] = $matches[1];
            if (!headers_sent()) {
                header('Location: '.$steamauth['loginpage']);
                exit;
            } else {
                ?>
                <script type="text/javascript">
                    window.location.href="<?=$steamauth['loginpage']?>";
                </script>
                <noscript>
                    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=<? 
 =$steamauth['loginpage']?>" />
                </noscript>
                <?php
                exit;
            }
        } else {
            echo "User is not logged in.\n";
        }
    }
 } catch(ErrorException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
}

if (isset($_GET['logout'])){
require 'SteamConfig.php';
session_unset();
session_destroy();
header('Location: '.$steamauth['logoutpage']);
exit;
}

if (isset($_GET['update']) || !empty($_SESSION['steam_uptodate']) && 
$_SESSION['steam_uptodate']+(24*60*60) < time()){
unset($_SESSION['steam_uptodate']);
require 'userInfo.php';
header('Location: '.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
exit;
}

// Version 4.0

?>
```

Comment: ну так код бы привели..

Comment: Извиняюсь, забыл